# Custom interrupt handler for user button on beagleboard

Tags: user-controls, beagleboard, interrupt-handling, led, gpio

I'm new to kernel module development. I'm writing a kernel module to handle the user button press. I need to glow on board led once the user button is pressed. How do I write a custom handler for user button as it is initial acquired by the kernel modules. Do I need to disable GPIO buttons in kernel config and write a complete module or I can just register my custom handler?

Answer (score 1):

You will first need to remove the module gpio_keys from kernel.
Use rmmod command for this - $> rmmod gpio_keys

I am not sure on glowing LED on interrupt button but I could handle the interrupt button using following code :

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/gpio.h>
#include <linux/irq.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <asm/io.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <asm/gpio.h>
#include <linux/platform_device.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/errno.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include<linux/sched.h>

#define GPIO 4

int var;

static irqreturn_t irq_handler(int irq, void *dev_id,struct pt_regs *regs)
{
    var++;
    printk("In the Interrupt handler, Count: %d\n", var);

    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}

int read_proc(char *buf,char **start,off_t offset,int count,int *eof,void *data )
{
   int len=0;
   if(offset>0)
   {len=0;}
   else{len  += sprintf(buf, "No of times button pressed: %d\n",++var);}
   return len;
}

void create_new_proc_entry()
{
  create_proc_read_entry("hello",0,NULL,read_proc,NULL);
}

static int __init hello_init(void)
{
       int errno = 0;
       printk("Hello: registered module successfully!\n");

       create_new_proc_entry();

      if((errno = gpio_direction_input(GPIO)) !=0)
      {
         printk(KERN_INFO "Can't set GPIO direction, error %i\n", errno);
         gpio_free(GPIO);
         return -EINVAL;
      }
       int irq_line = gpio_to_irq(GPIO);
       printk ("IRQ Line is %d \n",irq_line);

       errno = request_irq( irq_line, irq_handler, IRQF_TRIGGER_FALLING, "Interrupt", NULL );
      if(errno<0)
       {
         printk(KERN_INFO "Problem requesting IRQ, error %i\n", errno);
       }
       return 0;
}


static void __exit hello_exit(void)
{
  printk ("Unloading my module.\n");
  remove_proc_entry("hello",NULL);
  int irq_line = gpio_to_irq(GPIO);
  free_irq(irq_line,NULL);
  printk("Hello Example Exit\n");
  return;
}



module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);

// do some kernel module documentation
MODULE_AUTHOR("Deadman");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Interrupt Module");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

You can ignore the calls related to proc file system above. Just check on interrupt handler functions. This code worked fine for me.

Also if you want to use semaphores or any extra work during interrupt handling - follow this link for creating tasklets -

```
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-tasklets/
```

Essentially you might want to call tasklet_schedule in your interrupt handler code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If we can remove gpio_keys module that means it is a dynamic module. In that case the LED's that are acquired with this module are also released? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Well I am not sure on this. I had written the code above for some other purpose and I had to remove gpio_keys to handle the interrupt button. I am not aware of the LEDs though. I am pretty sure that you can handle interrupts using this code.